# Changing and updating values with arrays in C

Tags: c

I am having issues with my c program.  I am new to C programming and I have to write a program for class involving arrays.  I have to use two sets of arrays and allow the user to remove a location and add a new value into that spot. I created a max array of 20 but we have to use 1 thru 5 and allow the user to remove the value in either data set.  Here is what I have currently and I am getting a lot of errors saying I have ; and { in the wrong spots but it doesn't seem wrong when I go back to my text book and slides about arrays.  I created constant values under myarr1 and myarr2 and SIZE is set to 20.  Any and all help is appreciated I don't understand why i am getting all these errors.

```
int display_arr(int * count);
int remove_arr();
int myarr1[SIZE];

int main() {
    printf("Data confirmation and update program written in C.\n");

    int display_arr[6];
    //      display_arr[0]=NULLL;

    int counter = 6;

    my_identity();
    for (i = 0, i < SIZE; i++) {
      myarr1[i] = counter;
    }
    for (i = 0, i < SIZE; i++)
      printf("Array[%d] is %d.\n", i, myarr1[i];

        return EXIT_SUCCESS;
      }
      // deleting entry from data

    int remove_arr() {
      int position;

      printf("Enter the location where you wish to delete element\n");
      scanf("%d", & position);
    }

    int display_arr(int * count) {
        int i;

        for (i = 0; i < * count; i++)
          printf("%d", myarr1[i]);

        return 0;

      }
      //add an entry to data set
      //      int myarr()
  }
  //      int input;
  //      printf("Enter the value you would like to add to the end of the arry:");
  //      scanf("%d", &input);

//      if (array_select == 1){         // adds value to data set 1
//      myarr1[*counter] == input;
//      else
//      myarr2[counter] == input;       // adds value to data set 2

//return 0;
}
}
```

Comment: how is your problem related to linux?

Comment: When I run this through a compiler, there are a lot more error messages than just complains about wrong `;` and `}`. Start with the first error message, fix it, and run the compiler again. Then go on to the next error message and so on.

Answer (score 0):

Computer programming is about being precise. This means also following the rules exactly to the point, not more, not less.

In this case, I see two things

- Parenthesis/braces/brackets must be balanced:

  ```
  printf("Array[%d] is %d.\n", i, myarr1[i];
  ```

  Do you see the missing parenthesis at the end?
- Comma and semicolon are *not* the same:

  ```
  for (i = 0, i < SIZE; i++) {
  ```

  Do you see the first comma?

For the other problems, look at the compiler error messages.